# Accessing GAE Datastore from Server-side

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an Android app (client-side) and codes on GAE (server-side). The app stores a value in app engine's datastore. Now, on the server-side, I want to access that value, process it and return back the results to the app.

I know I can use [DatastoreService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService). I want to know if I have to connect to datastore when I am on server-side or not?

Thanks

Comment: no, gae app is already connected to gae datastore

Comment: not gae app. I mean the server-side.

Comment: what is your server side then? google compute engine? you said you have appengine on server side

Comment: I have app engine. when you said "gae app", you meant server-side? So, from your answer I understand that when I code on server-side I don't need to connect to datastore.

Comment: yes, of course, server side (I don't think you're able to run gae code on android :))

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will use this link which I think will do the job.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

Comment: yeah. also, i suggest to take a look at Objectify, it significantly simplify your data access code

Comment: Thank You :-)
I will look into it.